# Teams API: Setting presence only with user consent

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Recently the Teams API has been extended so that applications can set the availability / presence for a user logged into Teams: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-setpresence

However, the permissions for this API do not allow access with delegated permissions, only with permission type application:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-setpresence?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Am I right in assuming, that this means I will need an administrators consent from every tenant if I intend to build an application using this API?

Is it therefore impossible / impractical to implement this into my app that allows a user to set their presence based on the activity in my app? Because, and please correct me if I am mistaken, a user by themself cannot actually give my app the permission to do this. Right?

(Doesn't this make this api point sort of nearly useless?)

Comment: According to the description in the [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-setpresence?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#presence-sessions), it provides the app permission to set a user's presence state, so what you can do here is judge if the user can access this method to change the status because a method which will obtain access token through client credential flow can change a specific user's status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This API supports only Application permission, so on behalf of user token, you can not change the status where as using application token, you can update the status: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-setpresence?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions

Comment: Yes and No. If I understand you correctly, my basic assumption was correct, and I cannot use this API with delegated permissions (even if user Tiny Wang seems to suggest otherwise). If you know, could you also confirm that my other assumption is correct, that this means I will need an administrator's consent from every tenant if I intend to build an application using this API?

Comment: Application permissions are used by apps that run without a signed-in user present, for example, apps that run as background services or daemons. Only an administrator can consent to application permissions. Reference doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#permission-types